# Logitech mouse and keyboard don't wake up my macbook pro 13" (2020)

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth, sleep-wake, mouse

I have my macbook plugged into an external monitor, and when it goes to sleep I can't wake it back up with the keyboard or the mouse. They are both Logitech, MX keys and MX master 3. I can't figure it out for the life of me. As far as I can remember, the magic keyboard I had before was able to wake it up, but I'm not sure anymore.

I think this only happens when it goes to sleep automatically. If I send it to sleep, then I can wake it up with the keyboard or mouse.

thanks

Comment: Also, sometimes when it goes to sleep the screen goes dark grey (so it doesn't switch off completely) but the cursor stays on, in the upper left corner. It's weird

Answer (score 1):

I have to use the USB receiver for my Logitech devices to reliably wake my Mac. I'm not sure if I have a lot of 2.4 GHz interference or it just doesn't signal like Apple's devices. The Apple devices reliably work for me, third party devices, I love to connect them via USB to make them as reliable as Apple branded Bluetooth.